# JPQL IllegalArgumentException - unexpected token: SUM

Tags: java, mysql, jsf, maven, jpql

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token:
>   SUM near line 1, column 1 [SUM (e.quantidade) FROM
>   br.com.pmro.coad.modelo.Estoque e join fetch e.produtos prod GROUP BY
>   prod.id]

//CONSULTA 1 - FUNCIONANDO

```
return this.em.createQuery("FROM Estoque e join fetch
e.produtos",Estoque.class).getResultList();
```

//CONSULTA 2 - FUNCIONANDO

```
return this.em.createQuery("FROM Estoque e join fetch e.produtos prod
GROUP BY prod.id",Estoque.class).getResultList();
```

//CONSULTA 3 - DANDO PAU

```
return this.em.createQuery("SUM (e.quantidade) FROM Estoque e join fetch e.produtos prod GROUP BY prod.id",Estoque.class).getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Está faltando o select logo no começo, como você quer retornar um único valor que seria a soma e não o objeto inteiro.

"SELECT SUM (e.quantidade) FROM Estoque e join fetch e.produtos prod GROUP BY prod.id
return this.em.createQuery("SUM (e.quantidade) FROM Estoque e join fetch e.produtos prod GROUP BY prod.id",Estoque.class).getResultList();

Comment: Eu gostaria de retornar o objeto inteiro e não apenas a soma.

Comment: Como você usou o group by so colocar no SELECT prod,SUM(e.quantidade)

Comment: Consegui resolver mas de forma bem diferente. Obrigado por ter dado essa ajuda de qualquer forma.